# From constrained to unconstrained optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following convex optimization problem:
 \begin{equation}\label{prob}
\begin{aligned}
&\underset{{\bf W, \xi}}{\text{min}} & \frac{1}{2} ||{\bf W}||_2^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n C_{y_i}\max(0,1+ \underset{r \neq y_i}{\max} {\bf W}_{r}^T {\bf x}_i -  {\bf W}_{y_i}^T {\bf x}_i )) \\
& \text{subject to} & \forall i, \forall r \neq y_i, \quad {\bf W}_{y_i}^T {\bf x}_i- {\bf W}_{r}^T {\bf x}_i + \xi_i \geq 1\\
& &\forall i, \xi_i \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where ${\bf W}$ is a matrix of size $\mathbb{R}^{K \times d}, {\bf x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times d}, y_i \in \{1,2,...,K\} $,  $K$   is the number of classes. The matrix ${\bf W}$ stores weight vector for each class in its rows. $C_{y_i} = C / N_{y_i}$ is the regularization parameter weighted inversely by the number of data points in that class. ${\bf W}_{j}$ denotes the row of ${\bf W}$ corresponding to label/class $j$.

How can I convert this constrained problem into unconstrained?

Comment: Why do you think you *can* convert it to unconstrained?

Comment: Pathological answer: You can add the indicator function of the constraints to the objective and obtain an equivalent unconstraint problem. But I doubt this is any useful...

Comment: @MichaelGrant. I'm not thinking that I can convert to \emph{unconstrained} but you said [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079629/from-constrained-to-unconstrained-maximization-problem) using indicator functions as also suggested by. Second: Using indicator functions, I too do't think it is going to help. I'm planning to use Frank Wolfe to solve the above prob. similar to [paper](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v28/lacoste-julien13-supp.pdf) by converting structured SVM to unconstrained  structured SVM. Any idea how to solve my prob besides the above?

Comment: Indeed, indicator functions are rarely practical in and of themselves...